# Error "Гknown protocol" when request to server with ssl

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, proxy

I have some service, including next scripts:
1. Php cUrl script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain2/file/get');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

which get file outside server.

On outside server I have two virtual machines. First is web-server, which proxy request to **domain2** via nginx. Next is config for it:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name domain2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/webservice/domain2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/webservice/domain2_private.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/webservice/domain2_chain.crt;

    proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/webservice/domain2.crt;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/webservice/domain2_private.key;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/webservice/domain2_chain.crt;

    proxy_ssl_verify on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

    ssl_verify_client off;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://172.30.100.248:443/;
            proxy_read_timeout 20m;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
}
```

The *https://172.30.100.248:443* is local virtual machine with web-service, which give the file.

By the request I have an error:

> error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

and can't understand this error.

I checked the crt, it is configured right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error:
my nginx.conf file doesn't include addon config files with ssl configuration (but in nginx status it was Active and no errors). There was duplicate server_names.